# Is it possible to install an iOS app with altered xcdatamodel onto a device with the previous version already installed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

If I alter the xcdatamodel on my iOS app (e.g. add an entity and some attributes) then when I try to install the updated version of my iOS application when a previous version is already installed on the device(or simulator) - the installation fails. I’ve already been reading up on lightweight migrations for xcdatamodel bundles etc but cannot make it solve the installation issue. My question is; is it actually possible to install an iOS app (with altered datamodel) onto a device with the previous version in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well lightweight migration should work for what you want, and it's the better solution !
Check that if you need help http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration

If you are in real deep trouble you can delete the SQL store and recreate it in your persistentStoreCoordinator method. You will loose all the user data. That's good for debug but no so much in production.

Just add :

```
//delete the store
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:storePath error:nil];
    // recreate the store
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
```

int your :

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
```

in the if that look like :

```
if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
```

Comment: Hey Boris - Cheers for the advice. I had been using your suggested RayWenderlech doc already. I eventually found my problem. The url for the _managedObjectModel in my code was looking for a .mom file extension which was fine in my single-datamodel build but the new build had two data models (to facilitate the migration from old to new) - thus I needed to locate my _managedObjectModel file by using the extension .momd .

Comment: Haaa the old mom/momd problem glad you succeed